# How to show the numbers in Persian text in Objective C like 125 show "one hundred - twenty five"?

Tags: objective-c, persian

```
NSString *numberWord;
NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:125];
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
numberWord = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
```

//I want to show "صد و بیست و پنج"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the number formatter's locale to a Persian locale.

```
NSNumber *numberValue = @(125);
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa"]];
NSString *numberWord = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
```

This will output:

> صد و بیست و پنج

Comment: how i know which local languages supports Xcode? and thank

Comment: @RealmOfFire Checks the docs for `NSLocale` and related documentation for localization for iOS and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
func getTextOfNumber(num: Int, identifier: String) -> String {
    let number: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: num)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)

    return formatter.string(from: number) ?? String(num)
}

let text = getTextOfNumber(num: 230, identifier: "fa")
print(text)
```

*Output:*

> دویست و سی

Or use as **Extension**

```
extension Int {
func getText(identifier: String) -> String {
        let number: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: self)
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()

        formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)

        return formatter.string(from: number) ?? String(self)
    }
}

print(230.getText(identifier: "fa"))
```

> دویست و سی

Answer (score -2):

Or create a method :-

```
//Call this methods from you class to get the string by passing number and Locale string
-(NSString *)getNumberString:(NSNumber *)num withLocale:(NSString *)locale{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:locale]];
    return [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:num];
}
```

Get the string by passing the Number and your desired Locale

```
[self GetNumberString:@(1007) withLocale:@"fa"];//Use different Locale (en,es,sn)
```

Comment: Putting it in a method does not add something to the solution. The solution itself is identical to @rmaddy's answer. Moreover, your code infringes the naming rules of Objective-C.